# TeXnicCenter: Copying compilation errors [to google]

Tags: compiling, texniccenter, copy-paste

When a compilation error occurs in TeXnicCenter 2.02,
I would like to copy it from the "Build Output" window [to google]

So far I'm failing to do so, having to type manually the error description.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: In your compilation folder will be a `log` file. This should contain the same output.

Comment: TeX errors rarely give meaningful information. And when they do you basically know what the problem is e.g. `missing $ inserted` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than going through the TeXnicCenter's own log window, it is easier to look at the log file itself.

By compiling `doc.tex`, a log-file `doc.log` will be created. This contains the information the TeXnicCenter window displays. Open this with your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 2):

The authors of TeXnicCenter decided to show the log part without the possibility to copy text from there.

If you want to change this behaviour please ask the authors on the webside [www.texniccenter.org](http://www.texniccenter.org) to change this.

As said in comments and the other answer you have the possibility to copy the complete(!) error message in the `log` file.  TeXnicCenter shows only parts of the log file, because it only shows the error error messages and warnings and some relevant message like used MiKTeX version etc.  That makes it easier to see what is going on with your document ...